# Schedule script in python

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I am looking to schedule a code on my raspberry pi zero. The task would be to run a .py script to a pet feeder 3 times a day on specific times based on the system clock. I have tried to search it on the internet but the results kept on coming back for windows 7 task scheduler, however I need to run it on Raspbian.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: why not use `cron`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the schedule package:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule

It had worked for me in raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

cron works well to schedule the python script to run at certain times. It's much simpler than using the python schedule package.

Firstly, make sure your python script starts with a shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

and is executable

```
$sudo chmod 755 ./my-python-script.py
```

Then, in command line on the pi. Open a new cron tab

```
$sudo crontab -e
```

(you may also need to select an editor, nano is the easiest)

and schedule your script to run by adding the follow to the last line of the crontab (this will run every 8 hours)

```
0 */8 * * *  /path/to/my-python-script.py
```

or if you would like to log the output, use

```
0 */8 * * *  /path/to/my-python-script.py > /home/pi/Desktop/my_script_log.txt
```

Lastly, save and exit from nano (cntl + x) and restart your Pi.

If you are having issues, check the cron sys log

```
$grep cron /var/log/syslog
```

Use this site for working out the crontab interval syntax - [https://crontab.guru/](https://crontab.guru/#0_*/8_*_*_*)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so Rc.local didnt work, Ive tried everything, however Cron worked to autostart the launcher.sh.
Now, I need a second thing, where the scrip runs everyday 3 times in specific times, however the schedule 0.5.0 does not seem to work.
I have pip version 10.0.0 then I have managed to install schedule in the terminal, but when I try to run my script it comes back with an error, that the import schedule cant be found.
Do anyone know a solution for this?
[import schedule error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkbMV.jpg)
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkbMV.jpg)
Thanks

Comment: Okay let me correct it. The program did work on the system level, so it did works, however I could not test it as Thonny came up with an error for some reason.